# Issue with openjdk:17 docker image

Tags: java, docker, oraclelinux, openjdk-17

I'm using the `openjdk:17` docker image, the os is Oracle Linux Server v8.5. I ssh into the container with root user and found almost all common commands are not available. I have tried `ps`, `pidof` etc but getting command not found error. I'm trying to add a preStop hook to kill the java process gracefully but need a command to find the java process. Any idea how to achieve this?

Here is the output of `ls -l /proc/*/exe`. There sees to be a number of pid associated to the java process, but I'm sure I only have one. What is the clear way to find the pid and kill it? one liner is preferred

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 16:45 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 20:35 /proc/106/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 20:45 /proc/164/exe -> /usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/jshell
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 20:45 /proc/185/exe -> /usr/java/openjdk-17/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 21:15 /proc/self/exe -> /usr/bin/coreutils
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  3 21:15 /proc/thread-self/exe -> /usr/bin/coreutils
```

Comment: How about `ls /proc`?

Comment: this command works and show me a list files

Comment: The directory /proc contains (among other things) one subdirectory for each process running on the system, which is named after the process ID (PID). https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html In your container are most likely only one or two running processes, nvaigate to /proc/1 and `cat cmdline` to see which process has this pid.

Comment: Or even simpler `ls -l /proc/*/exe`.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I just updated the description with the output, would you take a look?

Comment: It's always PID 1, most likely this is also the `CMD`  you used in your Dockerfile? Btw. if you are not forced to use the oracle linux version simply use a debian based image: `openjdk:17-slim-bullseye`.

Comment: yes, this is the my `CMD`